# Event handling when changed variables can cause monitored variables change (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, state, event-loop

I have a problem with three variables (public properties). Let's say, I want to have a two-dimensional geometric vector.

We describe it with three properties as listed below: 
    MyVector: {BEGIN:integer?, END:integer?, LENGTH:integer}

("integer?" means it's of type `Nullable<int>`)

- We move the vector by setting BEGIN.
- We can change the vector's length by explicitly changing LENGTH.
- We can change the vector's length by changing END which changes LENGTH implicitly.

To this point, there's no problem.
But we have additional rules:

```
MyVector: {BEGIN:odd integer, END: odd integer, LENGTH: integer}
```

(we have no rule to LENGTH to be even)

**I have no control over what integers I receive! So I can't set a strict type like as in ADA.**

So when BEGIN is changed, we must check if input is odd. If not, we must justify it (let's say, it's moved randomly by 1 if LENGTH remains at least 0.)
When END is changed, we must do a check again. And we also need to set LENGTH, which calls a change event to LENGTH.
When LENGTH is changed, we must set END to BEGIN+LENGTH. This calls a change event to END.

And here's what (can) cause an event loop and other strange behavior.

I could break it down to three scenarios:

1. BEGIN is changed -> justification -> END is changed
2. END is changed -> justification -> LENGTH is changed
3. LENGTH is changed -> END is changed

From this point, I tried to implement state-transition automate, where states are:

```
enum VectorChangeStates{
relaxed,
begin_changed, begin_changes_end, exit_1,
end_changed, end_changes_length, exit_2,
length_changed, length_changes_end, exit_3,
unknown
}
```

I just can't get it working correctly!

**Bug is:**
When I set the BEGIN property, END is set and it sets LENGTH which sets END, so LENGTH goes totally wild! (of course it's not a vector and it's not changed randomly, but it takes too long to describe it)

Now here are some code snippets:

this is how my properties look like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LENGTHProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
"LENGTH",
typeof(int),
typeof(MyVector),
new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLENGTHChanged)));

public int LENGTH
{
get { return (int)this.GetValue(LENGTHProperty); }
set { this.SetValue(LENGTHProperty, value); }
}
```

Note: `this.SetValue()` sends the change event

Change event:

```
private void OnLENGTHChanged(int newValue)
{
// Avoid values lower than 0
if (newValue < 0)
{
this.LENGTH = 0;
return;
}

if (this.mActualState == VectorChangeState.Relaxed)
{
this.mActualState = VectorChangeState.length_changed;
this.HandleState();
}
}
```

where `this.mActualState` is:
    private VectorChangeState mActualState = VectorChangeState.Relaxed;

and `this.HandleState()` is managing the state-transitions. I won't copy that (because it would take too long to replace names in it). Error handling: if something goes wrong (e.g.: I'd call BEGIN.ToString(), but BEGIN is `null`, then `this.mActualState = VectorChangeState.Relaxed`

**Question:**
Can this problem be resolved by implementing a state-transition machine (or kinda like that)? If yes, am I thinking wrong? If not, what can be the solution?

I was working on this for nearly two days and whatever I implemented (state-machine, or not!), the bug was still there, I'm frustrated...

Thanks for your answers, and sorry for the long post!

**SOLUTION**
is marked. Actual code - which is a full "myVector" class - may come when stars align properly *(when I'll have time)*

Comment: Why is it necessary to allow setting both `LENGTH` and `END`?  Would it be acceptable to allow only one of those to be set, and have the other computed (read-only)?

Comment: IMHO you're overthinking this. Mike's suggestion is valid. Note that your "vector" really only has two pieces of information. Length and end are just two different ways of representing the same knowledge. Even if you can't restrict setting to one or the other, you can implement one in terms of the other. I.e. suppose you want to store length. Then when setting end, you just compute the new length based on start and the new end value and set length instead. Conversely, when retrieving end, you compute end based on start and length.

Comment: These vectors in the database are stored by their BEGIN and END, but user on GUI can set BEGIN and LENGTH. He can also modify it, so when it's loaded from the database, LENGTH is computed and can be changed.

I also got an idea to represent this by two of 3 properties, but I just can't avoid it. The user wants to set "4 inches long vector from point 7", then I must allow it.

Comment: And the user may want to set END and LENGTH 2 days from now and I don't want to rewrite code. (and also I don't want to write 3 times as much code as needed...)

Comment: Also, I'm not clear on what these rules are regarding odd integers.  Are you saying `BEGIN` and `END` must always be odd, unless the value of `LENGTH` requires `END` to be even?  If so, why is it possible to create a vector with an even `END` by setting `LENGTH` but not by setting `END` directly?

Comment: No, Mike. Let's say the DB accepts only odd numbers as BEGIN and END. So when the user sets END to 6, I must justify it to 5 or 7.

Comment: I see.  What rule do you use to decide whether you round to `5` or `7`?

Comment: It doesn't matter...
The real code sets `DateTime` values and justifies them to xy second long intervals. so every `DateTime?` variable (BEGIN, END) must be null, or justified and LENGTH must be multiply of xy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really, *really* think you should stick with just `Begin` and `End`, with `Length` being computed.  If the user wants to set a vector's origin and length, then use those numbers to derive the `End` when you create the vector.  If you go this route, then the dependencies only flow in one direction, which makes things *much* simpler.

You can use WPF's value coercion mechanism to compute `Length`, and also to make sure the `Begin` and `End` values are valid (e.g., make sure `Begin` doesn't come after `End`).

Observe:

```
public class MyVector : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BeginProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LengthProperty;

    public int? Begin
    {
        get { return (int?)GetValue(BeginProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BeginProperty, value); }
    }

    public int? End
    {
        get { return (int?)GetValue(EndProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(LengthProperty); }
    }

    public void Resize(int newLength)
    {
        if (newLength < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("newLength"");
        if (this.Begin == null)
            this.Begin = 1;

        this.End = this.Begin + newLength;
    }

    static MyVector()
    {
        BeginProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Begin",
            typeof(int?),
            typeof(MyVector),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(int?), OnBeginChanged, CoerceBegin));

        EndProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "End",
            typeof(int?),
            typeof(MyVector),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(int?), OnEndChanged, CoerceEnd));

        var lengthKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
            "Length",
            typeof(int?),
            typeof(MyVector),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(int), null, CoerceLength));

        LengthProperty = lengthKey.DependencyProperty;
    }

    private static void OnBeginChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.CoerceValue(EndProperty);
        d.CoerceValue(LengthProperty);
    }

    private static object CoerceBegin(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var vector = (MyVector)d;

        var begin = (int?)baseValue;
        if (begin > vector.End)
            return vector.End;

        if (begin % 2 == 0)
            return begin == 0 ? 1 : begin - 1;

        return baseValue;
    }

    private static void OnEndChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.CoerceValue(BeginProperty);
        d.CoerceValue(LengthProperty);
    }

    private static object CoerceEnd(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var vector = (MyVector)d;

        var end = (int?)baseValue;
        if (end < vector.Begin)
            return vector.Begin;

        if (end % 2 == 0)
            return end + 1;

        return baseValue;
    }

    private static object CoerceLength(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var vector = (MyVector)d;
        return (vector.End - vector.Begin) ?? 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
            "[MyVector Begin: {0}, End: {1}, Length: {2}]",
            Begin,
            End,
            Length);
    }
}
```

Test usage:

```
var v = new MyVector(); // => [MyVector Begin: , End: , Length: 0]

v.Begin = 3;            // => [MyVector Begin: 3, End: , Length: 0]
v.End = 5;              // => [MyVector Begin: 3, End: 5, Length: 2]
v.Begin = 8;            // => [MyVector Begin: 5, End: 5, Length: 0]
v.End = 10;             // => [MyVector Begin: 7, End: 11, Length: 4]
v.Resize(6);            // => [MyVector Begin: 7, End: 13, Length: 6]
```

Comment: This is awesome!
I didn't know about this CoerceValue thing, but it sounds like I need this, exactly!

I'll try this solution, shouldn't take more than 10 minutes.

Comment: Until then: I _really_ can't just say to forget about LENGTH being able to set from outside.
Can this CoerceValue be applied to LENGTH as well?

Comment: If you make `Length` writable, you end up with a two-way/mutual dependency with `End`, and that makes things very complicated.  It's easier if you let the user specify a `Length` in the UI layer, intercept the value and use it to derive the `End`, and then set the `End` on the vector.

Comment: What about a compromise in the form of a `Resize(int newLength)` method?  See updated answer.

Comment: I haven't got to modify length by now, but it's clear that coercing makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Right now, I can create a new "vector" and modify BEGIN and LENGTH as a maniac, and everything works well (I implemented this functionality at least two different ways already, so no happiness, but hope)

But if data is read from the database (and passed to MyVector through XAML binding), it's not loaded correctly. I have an idea in my mind that if END is null, don't even try to coerce anything...

Comment: I marked this as a solution, because coercing is new to me and shows a lot of possibilities when event handling gets out of control. Thanks!

By time, my "vector"'s code may come.